# Is Dart Editor (28355) now much slower on win7?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I upgraded to the latest Dart Editor (28355) both on Win7-32 and Win8-64 today. On Win7 it appears to run extremely slowly, on Win8 it is fine. Running both the Dart-Editor and the browser concurrently on Win7 I found unworkable. With just the dart-Editor running, it was still very slow to respond to input, but much better (4 v 25 seconds). I did reboot a couple of times in desperation. The Win7 machine is an older dual-core pentium with 4gb Ram running at about 2ghz (I'm on Win8 now). Previously I've had no major problems with the Dart-Editor on Win7 over a period of 6-months or more.

Is this a known problem with 28355?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a lot of folders in the 'Files' tab?

I find reducing the number of folders or right-clicking and selecting 'Don't Analyse' on some folders helps performance.

I have not experienced anything as dramatically slow as you have reported though.

Comment: That may be part of the problem, I'll try it.

Comment: I was looking at some SDK code in order to investigate a problem that I had. It appears that this caused the SDK folder to open and I presume "analyze" be enabled by default. I had previously noticed "analyze" working on a number of files that it didn't need to, however I never paid much attention to it other than that. Now that I know the potential for this problem, I'll pay more attention to "analyze". I hadn't upgraded Dart since I think 27025, whether I would have had the same problem with 27025, I don't know. That's how I see the situation at least, however I'll monitor it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that 28355 uses much more RAM than before (about 1GB total now, for me). If you have a browser running and a couple of other programs, 4GB will be used up pretty fast and cause slowdowns. I'm not sure about the difference with Windows 8, perhaps it has better memory efficiency.